# Trigger an Automator action with a sound

Tags: audio, automator, microphone

Is there any way to trigger an Automator action with a sound? I'd like to be able to record a sound and trigger an action every time my computer's microphone receives the sound.

Comment: Do you mean that Automator recognizes a sound that is coming from a microphone?

Comment: @Martín I think he means when mac heard a sound run some automator script.

Comment: @Am1rr yes but… from what I understand he wants it to be a “specific” sound recorded by him, which would be very difficult on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac OS X comes with speech recognition (check System Preferences > Speech panel) but it can't easily recognize a generic sound, only built-in commands.

Now, it is possible to make an automator action or script that is [triggered by an arbitrary phrase](http://www.atpm.com/15.11/speakable.shtml). However, if by "sound" you mean a beep, blip, crash or other sound that can't be  recognized as a string of phonemes (ie. speech in english or possibly another language) then we're into serious Objective C programming territory here.

Comment: Not even Objective C, that will require a very decent knowledge of C and low level sound analysis algorithms. My head hurts and I only imagined it.